# Overall time complexity of Heuristical Algorithm for travelling salesman problem [TSP]

Tags: algorithms, graphs, time-complexity, heuristics, traveling-salesman

I am trying to figure out the time complexity of a heuristical algorithm used to solve the Travelling Salesman Problem in a more efficient way than by brute force, ($\theta(n!)$ or similar)

1. The first step is to **compute Kruskal's Minimum Spanning Tree**, which to my best knowledge is of 
   $\theta(E+V)$, where E is the number of edges of the graph, and V the number of vertices.
2. Next, the algorithm finds a **minimum-length pairwise matching** of the odd degree vertices from the result of the MST graph. Min pairwise matching can solved in $\theta (V'logV')$, where $V'$ represents the vertices that are of odd deg.

My question is, **what is the overall time complexity of my Heuristical Algorithm**, is it the sum of the two time complexities of **1** and **2**?

For further reading on the heuristical algo, consult http://web.mit.edu/urban_or_book/www/book/chapter6/6.4.6.html

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any algorithm that first does $A$ of work and then $B$ of work will have done a total of $A+B$ of work. It doesn't matter what the algorithm is, or what $A$ or $B$ are.

You might be getting confused by steps that look complicated and/or by the fact that $A$ and $B$ are expressed in terms of $\Theta$. For this reason and in general, it is a good idea to try to compute $A+B$ as well as possible, and then finally expressing the sum in terms of Big Oh. Otherwise, you run the risk of performing voodoo, and not really understanding what $\Theta$ means.

Comment: Great, thanks! That is what I was looking for.